# How do I prototype a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I've searched SO and Google but unfortunately couldn't find an answer. I'm looking for the correct syntax to prototype a lambda. I've tried:

```
int g = [] () -> int;
```

But I get errors. Is there a way to prototype a lambda? If so, how?

Comment: No.  Why would you need to do this?  Just declare a normal function.

Comment: The power of a lambda is that you can define a function object that (optionally) captures variables from its context *at the callsite*! For other uses, you're typically better off declaring a regular function.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this SO [doc link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas#t=201702110629374323036). It's quite detailed! Check it out.

Comment: But how do I declare a function that takes a lambda of a specific signature (e.g. one that takes one int and returns a bool)? With function pointers, I'd use `typedef bool (*TheFunctionSig) (int)` and use `TheFunctionSig` as the parameter type of my function. What's the analog with accepting lambdas? I want to be able to capture values, so I can't use a classic function ptr.

Comment: Huh, found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109571/lambda-as-function-parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't prototype a lambda. You can create a function object holding the lambda expression, but that wouldn't be prototyping but rather definition. E.g.: `auto f = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };`
You can also declare a standard function pointer with a type corresponding to your desired lambda signature.