# Open MP: SIMD compatible function in SIMD loops?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmp, simd

Typically, I might write a simd loop like:

```
float * x = (float *) malloc(10 * sizeof(float));
float * y = (float *) malloc(10 * sizeof(float));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    y[i] = 10;

#pragma omp simd
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    x[i] = y[i]*y[i];
```

And suppose I have two tasks in mind:

```
float square(float x) {
    return x * x;
}
float halve(float x) {
    return x / 2.;
}
```

And an omp loop primitive:

```
void apply_simd(float * x, float * y, int length, float (*simd_func)(float c)){
    #pragma omp simd
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         x[i] = simd_func(y[i])
}
```

Is this legal within the parameters of SIMD? Or is the compiler going to produce less efficient code than if I explicitly inline everything?

Does writing:

```
float inline square(float x){ ... }
```

Change anything? Or can I expect to benefit from SIMD only if I explicitly write down the operation in terms of native functions/operators only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with optimization enabled (`-O3 -march=native`), modern compilers can reliably inline through function pointers *if* these conditions are met:

- the function-pointer has a compile-time constant value
- it's pointing to a function whose definition the compiler can see

That sounds simple to ensure, but **if this code is used in a shared lib on Unix/Linux (compiled with `-fPIC`)** then symbol-interposition rules mean that `float halve(float x) { return x * 0.5f; }`<sup>1</sup> can't inline even within the same translation unit.  See [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/).

**Use the `inline` keyword to allow inlining even when building a shared library**; like `static` it allows the compiler not to emit a stand-alone definition of the function at all, if it decides to inline at every call-site.

Use `inline` on `halve`, `square`, and `apply_simd`.  (Because `apply_simd` needs to inline into a caller that passes `halve` as a function arg.  A stand-alone definition of `apply_simd` is useless because it can't inline the unknown function.)  If they're in a `.cpp` instead of a `.h`, you might as well make them `static` as well or instead, otherwise just make them `inline`.

---

#### Do as much work as possible in one pass

I suspect you wanted to write something really inefficient like this:

```
apply_simd(x, y, length, halve);   // copy y to x
apply_simd(x, x, length, square);  // then update x in-place
// NEVER DO THIS, make one function that does both things
// with gcc and clang, compiles as written to two separate loops.
```

A loop that only does a copy-and-multiply by `0.5f` will usually bottleneck on memory bandwidth.  Modern CPUs like Haswell (or Skylake) have twice as much FMA/mul (or add) throughput (2x 256-bit vectors per clock) as they have store bandwidth (1x 256-bit vector per clock to L1d).  **Computational intensity matters.  Don't gimp your code by writing multiple loops that do separate trivial operations**

With any loop unrolling, or if data doesn't fit in L1d, the throughput for SIMD `x[i] = 0.25f * y[i]*y[i]` will be the same as for either of those operations alone.

I checked the asm output from g++ 8.2 and clang++ 6.0 [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E+//+for+size_t%0A%0Ainline++//+allows+inlining+even+with+-fPIC,+like+static%0Avoid+apply_simd(float+*+x,+const+float+*y,+size_t+length,+float+(*simd_func)(float+c))%7B%0A++++%23pragma+omp+simd%0A++++for(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+length%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A+++++++++x%5Bi%5D+%3D+simd_func(y%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainline+float+square(float+x)+%7B%0A++++return+x+*+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainline++//+Watch+what+happens+to+the+-fPIC+asm+if+you+comment+out+%22inline%22%0Afloat+halve(float+x)+%7B%0A++++return+x+/+2.%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test_separateloops(float+*__restrict+x,+const+float+*__restrict+y,+size_t+length)+%7B%0A++++//+SLOW,+DON!%27T+DO+THIS%0A++++apply_simd(x,+y,+length,+halve)%3B%0A++++apply_simd(x,+x,+length,+square)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.47916888921457,l:%274%27,m:62.66266266266266,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-O3+-fopenmp+-march%3Dhaswell+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B17%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:37.33733733733734,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:38.47916888921457,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-fPIC+-Wall+-O3+-fopenmp+-march%3Dhaswell+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:27.86422574736228,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-fno-pic+-Wall+-O3+-fopenmp+-march%3Dhaswell+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B17%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.656605363423154,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  Even with `__restrict` to tell it that x and y don't overlap, the compilers still made 2 separate loops.

---

### Pass a lambda as a function pointer

We can easily compose arbitrary operations into a single function using a lambda, and pass it as a function pointer.  This solves the above problem of creating two separate loops, while still giving you the desired syntax of wrapping the loop up in a function.

If your `halve(float)` function was a placeholder for something non-trivial, you can use it in a lambda to compose it with something else.  e.g. `square(halve(a))`

In earlier C++ standards, you need to assign the lambda to a function pointer.  ([Lambda as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109571/lambda-as-function-parameter))

```
// your original function mostly unchanged, but with size_t and inline
inline  // allows inlining even with -fPIC
void apply_simd(float * x, const float *y, size_t length, float (*simd_func)(float c)){
    #pragma omp simd
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
         x[i] = simd_func(y[i]);
}
```

C++11 caller:

```
// __restrict isn't needed with OpenMP, but you might want to assert non-overlapping for better auto-vectorization with non-OpenMP compilers.
void test_lambda(float *__restrict x, const float *__restrict y, size_t length)
{
    float (*funcptr)(float) = [](float a) -> float {
         float h=0.5f*a; // halve first allows vmulps with a memory source operand
         return h*h;    // 0.25 * a * a doesn't optimize to that with clang :/
    };

    apply_simd(x, y, length, funcptr);
}
```

**In C++17 it's even easier, and Just Works with a literal anonymous lambda:**

```
void test_lambda17(float *__restrict x, const float *__restrict y, size_t length)
{
    apply_simd(x, y, length, [](float a) {
        float h = 0.5f*a;
        return h * h;
      }
    );
}
```

These both compile efficiently with gcc and clang, to an inner loop like this **([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYWFFMOAGYA6JFtzqA9JfWGy64QQBe2APpEuABgCCX70qYlbHUrGxYmJnQAd2F1AKUlYHVsADdsNnUo4iR1AFpDAAUASW1ydUCAa2C9FiICbh8U9AJMdRYAB3amAE9XRwBbTAhDSNr1ACp1AA8yjDY9W1GiCe6yxxd3cvTgIiQykfQxiHGBzFdDMWUASmGl9VQrq64AdgEfEJCFdtIWYH6WdTofrtBwEQZ%2BD62MgQdZuZYETTyAAi6k8Wj4cUR2i2HF26LigkET3ekMhUy4AFY%2BARKSitCjTudLqgIN1KdTaU95G9fM8kX4/JZxn54mxggcxsIAI5iFikbC3Q7LKZXTSvCEfeVECQZKYTabogV8gU%2BUXBULqADqtVQOSiSDGDs66ViJHUu2C%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%2BwHaYhzosdnqYt651hTZGqQTi138mr30gz8yga5d/3ZSSx2kzN/MhVT6Q0rSdOLbxlJCQLgtCrHlNLfz2t5VDMIWlgxDdRNbvugEJrhikkXIjNZPkCwxzXdQ8YNblyqx6xq2BVhqyxOYFhwFQiHWhVacIkjEd4AA2Rl%2BO4DmKZ8awFCUFQ1GCLRtHVuph3CcbtcsYWuibcXhwWPRMBAEATYIYcjcTDsuQsFW1eZOTNzYLyFut0XDZ0GWNrYO7qkgpllDki0g42zChewEXbY9u5jj965yIeC3vFDzOdDHXOWTHAvNYrHCwfcdOberJ6vwl0c7nGP7MoBmGnkU7GPi%2BH4/gBIEQVOfy7FIGEu/hREUTRfmESN9i8UXs6%2BE4nGQnJKkaWZufQUGeOWTZXfOSx4murNeTHN6dWpNXV4eewbUgtRYxosDeLMcqzqsMrXCtZi5Ny%2BhOKib0W72zbgxb64CZwsX%2BouHuRoeS60DJ4T4ZVNw1DqKgC0qR0gOCILUeo6hErJVSgBZsIIohkAqFtcQvl3RIGCMAVAeCiJiGAP5Vu2ApjfDaNTdAt9XCtgPkzFmCMZJyS5n3LeN81JInRtpXS/N9LhDSLYIyJkIjRFiJZaytk8o5ABE5FybkJBSEBBtHyfkyqkl5iFMKkJNxRRivFWKZCkrCBSjINKdR%2BiZXdMInKyxjEFXYEkEq/liaVS6i4mwbCOFcIAkQIgbYSqWCScYYAbAxDGDIMASwnDgBOAIBEFglhhBIGiK4EpxhUDABpPIAAYi0ekAAOeQ0UOmgzAr0YB2AjaCH6L0Vs5hIYsUBsBC0KhIltHYfWIgrokAEGEGUJJXiKF%2BIFL1ZswghllTroMo2ozj4TPqj%2BZBcTfB7N8gQQwKFdnyHSIQQwMgrjMFkBSGQ5A2CyE8L89AshTr8EEBYjymher0F%2BUQAFHzPkVBAPIDpxgAAszwACc9BlYdLxZing9A0UUmeF8mQaLfn9BAMrQsysaV0p4Ayplys/nwvIMCmQvzhAgE8OQOFMhAWfLgLAFAGBgTlO8pQagYr2gStIGgQqwBlaeF5YYcp1ZjLUCImyoiSg5TdFkDC8gYrwxsCIHuXaBqBW/JwP8DgS42WEHlDOAgaRuXWvIHw7AqBqbSBkEapQ1YmBsqnGCQ1HzmCRLQOvZgBAiLcsgJ81spt5iyFyNaCIeQ9zyDyHYKOwI8j/EkIoh0wgojNiYHkR29JcliHXtNLl7kpAME%2BcGmQPzWUeo5VMDpytcjKzRREoqytjAaQwRAfAxB7AKEYOobQo85VQvkPIVUoKBD8FhfCx45AWEsBwPKiArbZAUvIFS%2BQzxjDLueFem9575Bos7YC9lsguU8r5VuxFyLUUYuxbi/FhLiWkrbfIX5/yu0vvfdaoViAICioXUuCgVAIAyrlSAYAHSeDkDVUwDV3KIDao9bq6OpArVGpNRGC1PRHXp0iQ6j1TrvV1DdWyr1PrqzhsoGa5sIb%2BxUv9RGxV0awX8FjfG%2BASb0r2zTYUEoeQM2VtyNm3NXk2AFtyEW209JS3lszbkatyJa31qNaISx0h6BHvbaBtl3be39sHZs1FPB1ATsICQUgS7Z3zvFQhpdPBV3r03VBz9PBMWaRRWizFBKeCeGeDwaKaLMNtpPVS%2BgKrH1Aog9y3l/LBXkGFcgNA8HJVIZQwhtDGGsPqu8nhgjT6iP6o4%2BRs1lGrVPttbRv1bWjKMddTWFjUxvW%2Bo44G7jHrQ18Zha2qN3BhNCECGJxN7LJOppkPkIOuRZV4PTaZLNOb8gqbUxpktvodMKf00iQzs2G0iCbWZizHawNPps32gd6gHMf2c5OtzHmyhedlT5md/nZuBcFZ%2B%2BQ9BjCYow8u%2BgHTMUqppXDslJ7HsZc5SIN9OWEVkp4JShgaXUfPvR1j7daRjJu3%2BWioAA))**.

```
.L4:
    vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
    vmulps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], ymm0
    add     rax, 32
    cmp     rax, rcx
    jne     .L4
```

clang unrolls some, and probably comes close to one 256-bit vector loaded+stored per clock, with 2 multiplies.   (A non-indexed addressing mode would make that achievable with unrolling to hide the two pointer increments.  Silly compiler. :/)

---

### Lambda or function pointer as a template parameter

With a local lambda as a template param (defined inside the function), the compiler can definitely always inline.  But (due to a gcc bug) this isn't currently usable.

But with only a function pointer, it doesn't actually help catch cases where you forgot to use the `inline` keyword or otherwise broke the compiler's ability to inline.  It only means the function address must be a dynamic-link-time constant (i.e. not known until runtime binding of dynamic libraries), so it doesn't save you from symbol interposition.  At *compile* time with `-fPIC`, the compiler still doesn't know if the version of a global function it can see will be the one that is actually resolved at link time, or if `LD_PRELOAD` or a symbol in the main executable will override it.  So it just emits code that loads a function pointer from the GOT, and calls it in a loop.  SIMD is of course impossible.

It does stop you from shooting yourself in the foot by passing function pointers around in ways that can't always inline, though.  Probably with `constexpr` you can still pass them around as args before using in a template, though.  **So you might want to use this if it wasn't for a gcc bug that stops you from using it with lambdas.**

C++17 allows passing an automatic-storage lambda with no captures as a function object.  (Previous standards required external or internal (`static`) linkage for functions passed as template params.)

```
template <float simd_func(float c)>
void apply_template(float *x, const float *y, size_t length){
    #pragma omp simd
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
         x[i] = simd_func(y[i]);
}


void test_lambda(float *__restrict x, const float *__restrict y, size_t length)
{
    // static // even static doesn't help work around the gcc bug
    constexpr auto my_op = [](float a) -> float {
         float h=0.5f*a; // halve first allows vmulps with a memory source operand
         return h*h;    // 0.25 * a * a doesn't optimize to that with clang :/
    };

    // I don't know what the unary + operator is doing here, but some examples use it
    apply_lambda<+my_op>(x, y, length); // clang accepts this, gcc doesn't
}
```

**clang compiles it just fine, but g++ incorrectly rejects that even with `-std=gnu++17`**

**Unfortunately, gcc has a bug ([83258](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258)) with using lambdas this way.**  See [Can I use the result of a C++17 captureless lambda constexpr conversion operator as a function pointer template non-type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606810/can-i-use-the-result-of-a-c17-captureless-lambda-constexpr-conversion-operator) for details.

**Still, we can use regular functions with the template.**

```
// `inline` is still necessary for it to actually inline with -fPIC (in a shared lib)
inline float my_func(float a) { return 0.25f * a*a;}

void test_template(float *__restrict x, const float *__restrict y, size_t length)
{
    apply_lambda<my_func>(x, y, length);   // not actually a lambda, just a function
}
```

Then we get an inner loop like this from g++8.2 `-O3 -fopenmp -march=haswell`.  Notice that I used `0.25f * a * a;` instead of doing `halve` first, to see what kind of bad code we get.  This is what g++8.2 does with that.

```
.L25:
    vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]   # ymm0 = 0.25f * y[i+0..7]
    vmulps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]   # reload the same vector again
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], ymm0        # store to x[i+0..7]
    add     rax, 32
    cmp     rax, rcx
    jne     .L25
```

Reloading the same vector twice to save instructions would possible be a good idea if gcc wasn't using an indexed addressing mode, which [stops it from micro-fusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) on Haswell/Skylake.  So this loop actually issues as 7 uops, running at best 7/4 cycles per iteration.

With unrolling, approaching the 2 read + 1 write per clock limit for wide vectors is apparently a problem for sustained operation, according to Intel's optimization manual.  (They say Skylake might sustain 82 bytes per clock, vs. the peak of 96 loaded + stored in one clock.)  It's especially unwise if the data isn't known to be aligned, and gcc8 has switched to an optimistic strategy for unknown-alignment data: use unaligned loads/stores and let the hardware handle cases when there isn't 32-byte alignment.  gcc7 and earlier aligns the pointer before the main loop, and loads the vector only once.

---

**Footnote 1:  Fortunately gcc and clang can optimize `x / 2.` into `x * 0.5f`**, avoiding promotion to `double`.

Using multiply instead of divide is possible without `-ffast-math` because `0.5f` is exactly representable as a `float`, unlike fractions where the denominator isn't a power of 2.

But note that `0.5 * x` does *not* optimize to `0.5f * x`; gcc and clang do actually expand to `double` and back.  I'm not sure if that's a missed optimization vs. `x / 2.`, or if there's a real semantic difference that stops it from optimizing a double constant to a float when it can be represented exactly as a `float`.

Comment: this is one of the most comprehensive deployments of knowledge on any topic that I have ever run across.  Amazing. Thank you.  With respect to all of this, the goal was syntax and code markup for reuse--but your response was profound.  I will check these this godbolt out.